# Holoviews: How to wrap multiple RGB images into a Dataset and display them correctly?

Tags: python, holoviews

I have a dataset of RGB images as a `numpy array` of shape `(n, height, width, 3)`. I want to wrap the data into a `hv.Dataset` and visualize it (with `bokeh`) such that:

- A slider can be used to select one of the `n` images.
- Each image is displayed in its correct aspect ratio and orientaton.

I'm primarily interested in a solution without `xarray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, though I think there's probably a cleaner approach declaring an `hv.Dataset` wrapping the input array:

```
import numpy as np, holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

x,y = np.mgrid[-50:51, -100:101] * 0.1

def ms(k):
    r = 0.5*np.sin(np.pi  +k*x**2+y**2)+0.5
    g = 0.5*np.sin(x**2+k*y**2)+0.5
    b = 0.5*np.sin(np.pi/k+x**2+y**2)+0.5
    return np.dstack([r,g,b])

a = np.stack([ms(i) for i in [1,2,3,4]])

hv.HoloMap({i:hv.RGB(a[i-1,:,:,:], bounds=(-1,-0.5,1,0.5)).opts(data_aspect=1) for i in [1,2,3,4]})
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a valid alternative to me, but I'm still missing a way to get the aspect ratio right for non-square images, i.e. if you do something like `np.mgrid[-50:51, -100:101]`.

Comment: There are a lot of aspect and width/height options described at http://build.holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html ; here I'm not sure which one is the "correct" aspect ratio (square pixels? square plot? Equal area in data space?). E.g. add `.opts(data_aspect=0.5)` at the very end if you use that mgrid and want square pixels; other options for `aspect`, `data_aspect`, `frame_width`, and `frame_height` give other results if that's not what you want.

Comment: With "correct" I refer to the original aspect ratio of the image (photo), just like every image viewer I know would display it. So yes, square pixels in other words. If you please could include the `.opts(data_aspect=0.5)` part into the answer I could accept it.

Comment: I don't think this situation is comparable to an image viewer where there is only one coordinate system (pixels), which is why there is no one correct answer here. Here there are three independent sets of coordinates: the array shape (rows and columns), the size in data space (which could be inches, lat/lon, etc.), and the size on the screen (pixels wide by pixels high). You need to decide which of those should control the size you see, and they are all valid options. If you want there to be one answer to the original question, it should be edited to request square pixels explicitly!

Comment: In any case, I've updated the code to declare data_aspect=1 to make the displayed shape match the data shape, and also declare the shape in data space (-1,1) x(-0.5,0.5) in a way that reflects the underlying array shape (101x201). That way all three coordinate systems line up in the way you expect (twice as wide as tall, with square pixels).